# SSH ignores keyfile, wrongly asks for password

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

For work, I am SSH-ing into a server. I haven't done this for months, so something has changed  where it now asks me for a password. Previously, after authenticating it would work.  Here's what I typically write to ssh in: `ssh  -p2222 username@123.12.123.123`

I looked at the debug info, and it showed that the server wasn't even asking for the appropriate keyfile.  Instead, it first offers an public key that I deleted (id_rsa)..then it turns to private keys...then it asks for a password, which I shouldn't need.

```
debug1: Found key in /Users/myname/.ssh/known_hosts:40
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myname/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

However, when I specify the identity file, it works: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/correctkey username@123.12.123.123`!

**What do these errors mean, and how do I get ssh to work without getting prompted for a password?**  This is important because I use the GUI called [Fugu](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/fugu/) --the only GUI for SCP available--and I can't use the -i option in it!

Is there something on the server side of the equation that I need to get fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: If it works when you're manually specifying the client-side ID file, the problem is probably on the client side.

Comment: You must configure SSH to know about non-standard private keys, see my suggestion below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the names of the files with keys to defaults.

```
~/.ssh/correctKey --> ~/.ssh/identity (on client machine)
~/.ssh/correctKey.pub --> ~/.ssh/identity.pub (on server machine)
```

Is that not possible?

Comment: So I would change `correctKey` to `id_dsa` on both the client and server?  I'll try this with sysadmin soon.

Comment: @ridicter Yes. correctKey -> id_dsa (on client) and correctKey.pub -> id_dsa.pub (on server). If this is a DSA key, that is, and you are using protocol version 2.

Comment: @ridicter I think you just need to do this on the client. Because the "-i" option seems to work for you, means that the public key is correctly installed on the server. Just change correctKey to id_dsa on the client, so ssh will try it automatically. This is a DSA key, right?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a non-default private key file (e.g., `~/.ssh/correctKey`), you can configure SSH to be aware of and try using that alternate key by adding an `IdentityFile` directive to your `~/.ssh/config` file (creating that file in the process if it does not already exist). For example,

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/correctKey
```

And there are many other options you can configure in that file too, such as specifying the default port to use on a particular host (e.g., always use port 2222 when logging into 123.12.123.123, or the default username. See [`sshd_config(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) for details.

**Update** If your GUI app (Fugu) can't directly read SSH settings from `~/.ssh/config`, it appears you can manually pass options to SSH using its "Additional SSH Options" text box:

[image: screenshot of Fugu]

You could try passing `-i ~/.ssh/correctKey` via that text field.

Comment: I forgot that I actually did this a few weeks ago when I was trying to figure things out.   Yes, this works and makes it easy to ssh; however, I can't use the `config` file when using a GUI SCP client.  Is there any way to reset things so that I don't have to go through all this wizardry?

Comment: Does your GUI client not invoke the `ssh` command-line tool, like does it implement SSH internally or something? Or is your GUI app running as a different user which doesn't have read permissions to the private key or `config` file? Several GUI clients which I use that deal with Git over SSH _do_ respect `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: I added a workaround specifically for your Fugu GUI app you might try, see my updated answer

Comment: Hey Stuart,  I actually tried your Fugu answer a few weeks ago as well.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work.  That's why I said I can't use options with Fugu.  It's buggy and hasn't been updated in ages.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried any other OS X SFTP/SCP apps? I prefer Panic's Transmit app, but have used Cyberduck in the past and heard decent things about Macfusion. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25661/whats-a-good-graphical-sftp-utility-for-os-x

Comment: (In case you can't tell, I'm suggesting that maybe Fugu just isn't the best app to use if it doesn't let you customize SSH)